# Fix cannot find symbol mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this); symbol: variable mInterstitialAd location: class Ads

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm integrating admob ads in my application with java but getting this

> cannot find symbol mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this); symbol:
> variable mInterstitialAd location: class Ads

. Please check the util/Ads.java & AndroidManifest.xml file and help me to fix it. I'm not able to fix this.

***util/Ads.java***

```
package com.indiapps.documentscanner.util;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class Ads {
    public static void showAds(Context context) {


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTime = sharedPreferences.getLong("lastTime", 0);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

        if (currentTimeMillis - lastTime > 60000) {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putLong("lastTime", currentTimeMillis);
            editor.apply();
            Log.d("AAA","showAds");
        }
    }
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.indiapps.documentscanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name="com.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admod_app_id"/>
        <!-- HUNGDH -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.camscanner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:noHistory="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:noHistory="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>


        <activity
            android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.camscanner.MyPDFActivity"
            android:label="@string/my_pdf"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.camscanner.FilterImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/filter_image"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.camscanner.KnifeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.camscanner.MySettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <!-- DOCUMENT SCANNER -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.gpaddyv1.documentscanner.activities.SimpleDocumentScannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/from_gallery"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <!-- IMAGE TO PDF -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.gun0912.tedpicker.ImagePickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_picker" />

        <!-- OPEN NOTE SCANNER -->
        <activity
            android:name=".OpenNoteScannerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_open_note_scanner"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GalleryGridActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/my_gallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <!-- PHOTO EDITOR -->

        <activity android:name="com.gpaddyv1.documentscanner.process.view.ProcessImageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.joshuabutton.queenscanner.sign.view.SignActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.joshuabutton.queenscanner.process.view.CombineBitMapActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.gpaddyv1.documentscanner.document.DocumentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.joshuabutton.queenscanner.handle.HandleActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.indiapps.documentscanner.listdoc.DocsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar1">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: does InterstitialAd have a constructor that takes an instance of Ads as param?

Comment: It is always a good idea to declare variable before using them ...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare `mIntersitialAd`, you can do that right after the class opening braces.

```
public class Ads {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public static void showAds(Context context) {
      //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting error 

Comment: Did you add the line `private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;` ?

Comment: yep, but still same error

Comment: facing same problem when i,m using dependency of mopub, inmobi